# How to make itertools.permutations() to write each example on a file by modifying the code - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools, python-3.7

This is the code of [itertools.permutations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations):

```
def permutations(iterable, r=None):
    # permutations('ABCD', 2) --> AB AC AD BA BC BD CA CB CD DA DB DC
    # permutations(range(3)) --> 012 021 102 120 201 210
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    r = n if r is None else r
    if r > n:
        return
    indices = list(range(n))
    cycles = list(range(n, n-r, -1))
    yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices[:r])
    while n:
        for i in reversed(range(r)):
            cycles[i] -= 1
            if cycles[i] == 0:
                indices[i:] = indices[i+1:] + indices[i:i+1]
                cycles[i] = n - i
            else:
                j = cycles[i]
                indices[i], indices[-j] = indices[-j], indices[i]
                yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices[:r])
                break
        else:
            return
```

I want it instead of adding the permutations into a list, to write each permutation it finds to a .txt file immediately not by looping the list and writing them into the file.

Comment: Why not write the *result* of using the function to a file?

Comment: Okay, cool. What's stopping you from doing that? Do you know how to open files? Do you know how to write to them? Please read [ask].

Comment: I know how to open and write files.

Comment: @PatrickArtner That's not going to be the same if `r == 0`.

Comment: the code is a `copy&paste` from https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations ... what did you code?

Comment: @mkrieger1 hoppla - youre right ... r = 0 wouldn't make any sense though - but it should return [] and not them perms of n.

Comment: I don't know, but I think the Python devs did know what they were doing.

Answer (score 3):

The whole point of `itertools` is that values are produced lazily and not as lists. You don't need to change the code of `permutations`, all you need to do is loop over the permutations *as they are produced* and then write them to a file.

```
for p in permutations(your_iterable):
    # your code to write p to a file here
```

Note that at no point there's a list involved in this code. `permutations(your_iterable)` is an iterator you can explicitly pull values out of with `next` or implicitly by employing a `for` loop.

> it is a very large amount of permutations and causes a memory error

I am trying to tell you that `permutations(your_iterable)` can never produce a memory error in any non-artificially-contrived scenario if you don't explicitly make a list out of `permutations(your_iterable)` yourself. The iterator produces *one* permutation at a time which you can write to a file without ever holding all permutations in RAM.

> I am passing a list of length 110 to `itertools.permuations`

This is not a problem with the standard library or values in RAM.

Your code will produce

15882455415227429404253703127090772871724410234473563207581748318444567162948183030959960131517678520479243672638179990208521148623422266876757623911219200000000000000000000000000

permutations. There is no file system on the planet with enough storage space to write these permutations to.

Also, there's not enough time left until the heat death of the universe to compute all these permutations, even if you could compute one in a nanosecond.

```
>>> from math import factorial
>>> factorial(110)/(10E9*3600*24*365)
>>> 5.0362935740827724e+160 # years
```

> 4 is the second parameter for permutations

Ok, in that case your file would require around 1.7 GiB of space if you stored each permutation as a string of minimum length 13 akin to `'(0, 1, 2, 3)\n'` with one byte per character.

```
>>> perms = sum(1 for _ in permutations(list(range(110)), 4))
>>> perms*13/(2**30)
>>> 1.677529625594616
```

That's manageable - but it could require much more space if the objects in your list had longer string representations. We can't tell you why you get a memory error without seeing your code.

Comment: I want to write them when they are produced not by looping.

Comment: @JohnnyP. this code writes each permutation to a file as soon as it is produced. "Not by looping" makes no sense here, you have to have a loop somewhere if you want to do the same thing (writing) for multiple other things (permutations).

Comment: @JohnnyP., it looks like this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why are you preoccupied with whether there's a loop or not? What are you _actually_ trying to accomplish?

Comment: @JohnnyP. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756096/understanding-generators-in-python

Comment: Because it is a very large amount of permutations and causes a memory error.

Comment: @JohnnyP., then you should be posting _your code_ and asking about _the memory error_. This isn't a problem with Python's standard library code, it's a problem with _your_ code.

Comment: It reurns a memory error because there are billions of permutations.

Comment: @JohnnyP., not because of the code you're asking about. It's a problem with how you're using the standard library, which you aren't showing us.

Comment: @JohnnyP. well has your hard drive enough space for billions of permutations? ...

Comment: How much space do I want?

Comment: ...how should _we_ know how much space you want? Again, you _haven't shown us **anything**_ useful to understand your problem. Show us _your_ code, tell us about your data set, ask about the memory error, and then maybe we can help you.

Comment: @timgeb you wrote 'The iterator produces one permutation at a time which you can write to a file without ever holding all permutations in RAM.', but how?

Comment: I use itertools.permutations(a list of lenght 110, 4)

Comment: @JohnnyP., I'm going to say this one more time, then I'm going to leave. **You _must_ show us _your_ actual code.** "A list of length 110, 4" doesn't make any sense. Lists have one length, not two. Are you actually doing something with numpy arrays? We literally _**cannot** help you_ the way you're asking. The problem isn't in the standard library. Please read [ask], then try again.

Comment: 4 is the second parameter for permutations.

Comment: @JohnnyP. "but how" <- by producing values on the fly, not as lists. If you want to know how iterators are implemented, feel free to read the CPython source code.

Comment: @JohnnyP. are you aware that you are trying to store factorial(110) permutations?

Comment: @timgeb The second parameter of permutation is 4 so I want to store 110*109*108*107.